# PHP Smalot PdfParser get certain section

Tags: php, pdf

I need help about PHP Smalot\PdfParser. https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser

Does anybody know how to get or access certain section.

Example. Invoice and want to get access to items/products object section as Object/Array

getText method works but retrieves all the text on invoice.

Thanks alot!

Comment: PDFs don't have "sections", they just have pages and runs of text. The [usage docs](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser/blob/master/doc/Usage.md) show how to get both, and for the latter, you can also get x,y coordinates of the text run. It will be up to you to determine if one run of text is close enough to another for your own definition of a "section".

Answer (score 0):

You could use some loop like this:

```
$metaData = $pdf->getDetails(); //Gets PDF metadata
$xtargetTextCoordinate = "12.345" ///////////USE YOUR OWN
$ytargetTextCoordinate = "678.90" ///////////USE YOUR OWN

//Going through each PDF's page...

for ($x=0 ; $x < $metaData['Pages']; $x++ ){ 
    //Reset variables
    $streamOfThisPage = [];
    $streamOfThisPage = $pdf->getPages()[$x]->getDataTm(); 
    $targetText= "";

    //Going through each key element of this page...
    foreach($streamOfThisPage as $arrayEle){  
        if( ($arrayEle[0][4] == $xtargetTextCoordinate ) && ($arrayEle[0][5] == $ytargetTextCoordinate ) ){  //X & Y depend of your document structure...
          $targetText = "";

          //Remove unecessary data if any
          $thisRowWords = explode(" " , $arrayEle[1] );
          $referencePeriod = $thisRowWords[0];
          foreach($thisRowWords as $position => $word){
              $targetText = $targetText . $word . " ";
          }
    }
 }
 echo $targetText;
```